# Jekyll Image Breaking - No New Images Will Load

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

Using Github Pages to serve a comic book project I'm working on. The next is releasing Wednesday aaaaannd of course, Jekyll is deciding to not serve/recognize any *new* images. And that's key; it's only *new* images that Jekyll isn't recognizing.

Go to issue 1's image folder, [assets/chapter-one/p1.jpg](https://abductedthecomic.com/assets/chapter-one/p1.jpg), and it loads just fine

Go to [assets/chapter-three/p1.jpg](https://abductedthecomic.com/assets/chapter-three/p1.jpg) and you get a 404.

And [it's *definitely* in the repo.](https://github.com/zherring/abducted-thecomic/blob/master/_includes/assets/chapter-three/p1.jpg)

I've tried copying files from chapter-one over to chapter-three. No luck. I've also tried adding new images downloaded from the internet (so it's not any of the image compression algos I'm using etc)...still no dice. It loads on the old images, it 404/breaks on anything new.

Any idea on what's the matter? I'm utterly baffled by what's going on here. I've updated Jekyll to run on the most current, updated my gems etc. with no dice. Help?

Thanks in advance, all.

Comment: When you build it locally, does that asset get copied over to the _site folder? Is the image part of a published article? I.e. is the markdown file it’s associated with set up with a publish date in the past?

Comment: Also, worth checking out answers to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185926/image-not-copied-by-jekyll-assets

Comment: @MartinPeck Thanks for the response. It is a part of a published article, but it is not getting copied over to _site folder.

Comment: @MartinPeck Just checked the question linked - these images are very different though, only thing similar is the naming convention. I've also tried adding completely unrelated images, also not compiling those to _site.

Answer (score 1):

Your "old" images (e.g. `assets/chapter-one/p1.jpg`) are inside the `assets/` directory at the root of the repository.

The "newer" images (e.g. `assets/chapter-three/p1.jpg`) are inside the `_includes/assets/` directory.
Move these "newer" images into the `assets` directory at the root and all images shall get rendered as expected.

Comment: Ah cool, it was a boneheaded mistake on my end. Eeesh.

What's the difference between `_includes/assets` and `assets/` ?